# How do I configure server to serve the php version of a page before the html version?

Tags: php, html, apache, .htaccess

I am converting some pages on my website to use php.

http://vidalingua.com/blog/top-travel-blogs-germany.html
http://vidalingua.com/blog/top-travel-blogs-germany.php

I don't want to remove the html version because there are some backlinks pointing to it that include the html extension.

How do I get my Apache server to serve the php version of the page instead of the html version if the file extension is not specified?

http://vidalingua.com/blog/top-travel-blogs-germany

Ideally, I would like a solution that works anytime there are two files with different extensions.

Comment: You could do it with rewrite module.

Comment: Have a look to Apache "URL rewriting" capabilities, (coupled to some cache mecanism, using simply HTTP [and/or via your PHP framework], in case your PHP code does not need to be executed on each request)

Comment: I think you want to always serve the PHP version, regardless if .html, .php OR not extension was specified.

Comment: @Amin Correct. I want to always serve the PHP version, without having to remove the .html version so backlinks from other sites don't return not found. If maintaining .html and .php versions of the same page negatively impacts SEO please let me know.

Comment: @MarcBolh it does yes, having different URLs with same content, is duplicated content. What you can do, is check URL, and if it contains .html just redirect to PHP version. This way backlinks also get updated.

Answer (score 0):

THis should point you into the right direction:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} ^(.+)\.html$
RewriteCond %1.php -f
RewriteRule ^/?blog/(.+)\.html$ /blog/$1.php [END]
```

In case you receive an internal server error (http status 500) using the rule above then chances are that you operate a very old version of the apache http server. You will see a definite hint to an unsupported `[END]` flag in your http servers error log file in that case. You can either try to upgrade or use the older `[L]` flag, it probably will work the same in this situation, though that depends a bit on your setup.

This rule will work likewise in the http servers host configuration or inside a dynamic configuration file (".htaccess" file). Obviously the rewriting module needs to be loaded inside the http server and enabled in the http host. In case you use a dynamic configuration file you need to take care that it's interpretation is enabled at all in the host configuration and that it is located in the host's `DOCUMENT_ROOT` folder.

And a general remark: you should always prefer to place such rules in the http servers host configuration instead of using dynamic configuration files (".htaccess"). Those dynamic configuration files add complexity, are often a cause of unexpected behavior, hard to debug and they really slow down the http server. They are only provided as a last option for situations where you do not have access to the real http servers host configuration (read: really cheap service providers) or for applications insisting on writing their own rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).